# my pythonpath has 'register2',why i can't import it

Tags: python, django

```
import sys
print sys.path

['D:\\zjm_code\\register2', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python25.zip', 'D:\\Python25\\DLLs', 'D:\\Python25\\lib', 'D:\\Python25\\lib\\plat-win', 'D:\\Python25\\lib\\lib-tk', 'D:\\Python25', 'D:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages']
```

and

```
#from django.core.management import setup_environ
from register2 import settings
#setup_environ(settings)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\zjm_code\register2\b.py", line 4, in <module>
    from register2 import settings
ImportError: No module named register2
```

why ,

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When directory `'D:\\zjm_code\\register2'` is on `sys.path`, this means you can import modules and packages that are **INSIDE** that directory.

To import the directory `register2` itself, two conditions:

1. its **parent**, `'D:\\zjm_code'`, must be on `sys.path`; **and**
2. file `'D:\\zjm_code\\register2\\__init__.py'` must exist

`__init__.py` is the code that actually executes when you "import the directory".

Answer (score 0):

lol because it tries to import something from register2 but it cannot since there isn't D:\zjm_code on the path..